# functional form of exec in q

Tags: kdb

consider the flowing example:

```
q)\l sp.q
q)exec (qty;s) from sp
300 200 400 200 100 100 300 400 200 200 300 400
s1  s1  s1  s1  s4  s1  s2  s2  s3  s4  s4  s1
```

I want to write it in functional form, the most obvious way for me to do is:

```
q)?[sp;();();(`qty;`s)]
300 300 300 300 200 300 200 200 400 200 200 200
```

but it can't give me the correct result. The result is not intuitive to me, why this form can't work?

I have to do:

```
q)value ?[sp;();();`qty`s!`qty`s]
300 200 400 200 100 100 300 400 200 200 300 400
s1  s1  s1  s1  s4  s1  s2  s2  s3  s4  s4  s4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [wiki](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/funsql/#exec) only states that a dictionary is required for multiple columns, not why as far as I can see. To see how q is interpreting your query you can use `parse`. For the query you have given above:

```
q)parse"exec (qty;s) from sp"
?
`sp
()
()
,(enlist;`qty;`s)
```

Here we can see it is not quite as simple as passing a list of column names.

If you want to pass the columns names directly you can "exec" that way:

```
q)sp`qty`s
300 200 400 200 100 100 300 400 200 200 300 400
s1  s1  s1  s1  s4  s1  s2  s2  s3  s4  s4  s1
```

Note that this only works with unkeyed tables in memory (no partitions). If the table is keyed you can run `` (0!sp)`qty`s `` where `0!` is a shortcut to key by no columns.

Answer (score 4):

As Thomas pointed out - you should parse the exec statement and recreate its output in functional form, which would be

```
q)?[sp;();();enlist,`qty`s]
300 200 400 200 100 100 300 400 200 200 300 400
s1  s1  s1  s1  s4  s1  s2  s2  s3  s4  s4  s1
```

Comment: `enlist` creates a list from its argument(s). The enlist comma is creating the parse-tree form that the functional select recognises, i.e. ``(enlist;`qty;`s)~enlist,`qty`s``